# Why am I getting ReferenceError: db is not defined

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, express, axios

For some reason I cannot get axios to connect to the DB. Its is a MSQL server and when I use app.get in the server file I can get data returned but when using express DB connection just doesn't persist. In postman I can return a result with all my code on server.js receiving the entire table. This is what I want. When moving everything to axios and routing it to have less code on my server nothing returns anymore. nothing is broken except i get ReferenceError: db is not defined in nodemon.

HomePage

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const morgan = require('morgan')

//middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))

//Connect to DB
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user     : 'root',
    password : '******',
    database : 'avengers'
})

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log('MySql Connected...')
})

//Routes
app.use('/avengers', require('./routes/avengerRouter.js'))

//error handling
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err)
    return res.send({errMsg: err.message})
})

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log("The server is running on port 9000")
})
```

Server.js

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import AvengersTable from './AvengerTable.js'


function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

export default function Main(){

    const [tableState, setTableState] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getTableData() {
            axios.get('/avengers')
            await delay(300)
            .then(res => {
                // setTableState(res.data)
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.errMsg))
        } getTableData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="Main">
            {/* <AvengersTable tableState={tableState}/> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

avengerRouter.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const avengerRouter = express.Router();

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

avengerRouter
    
    // all data from avengers table http://localhost:9000/avengers
    .get('/', (req, res) => {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM avengers.avengers'
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)
            console.log(result)
        })
    })

module.exports = avengerRouter;
```

Comment: Because you did not import `db` in your `avengerRouter.js` file.

Comment: MSQL - as in MS SQL Server? (Or as in mSQL, aka Mini SQL?)

Comment: I added an answer please check it out @Cody Whitt

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `db.js` that includes a DB connection.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user     : 'root',
    password : '******',
    database : 'avengers'
});

export default db;
```

Usage of db at top of your `HomePage`

```js
const db = require('./db.js');

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log('MySql Connected...')
});

// Other codes goes below
...
```

And finally usage in your `avengerRoute.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const avengerRouter = express.Router();
// Forgotten line here
const db = require('./db.js');

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

avengerRouter
    
    // all data from avengers table http://localhost:9000/avengers
    .get('/', (req, res) => {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM avengers.avengers'
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)
            console.log(result)
        })
    })

module.exports = avengerRouter;
```

Comment: I'M getting an error 
export default db;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: `module.exports = db` fixed the server side crashing but react now has over 20 errors.

Comment: You need just import db connection to `avengerRoute`. That is the point.